# Error in Portuguese passport

Tags: passports, europe, consulates, portuguese-citizens

I am Brazilian with Portuguese citizenship. Last week, I went to the Portuguese Consulate to apply for a new passport for my 3-year-old daughter, as her previous passport would expire in a few months.

Today, I received her new passport with two problems that I may affect my daughter's future travels:

1. Her height was not updated, so it has the same height she had when she was 1 year old.
2. She looked down when taking the picture and was not looking straight at the camera.

What should I do? Are those major problems that could prevent me from entering another country? Should I contact the Portuguese Consulate in order to update her passport? I called them but they told me to send an e-mail, which I think will be totally ignored.

== Update

Portuguese consulate never answered my e-mail. 
I went to Netherlands without issues with her and no one asked about anything related to these problems. I think this info is not important for small children, probably.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: My first thought is that you should send the e-mail they suggest and wait to see whether it is in fact ignored.

Comment: Most countries are not strict about pictures of small children, as it can be quite difficult to get them to look straight into the camera.

Comment: @phoog I´ve sent then an e-mail and tell you what happened as soon as they reply

Comment: The height is going to be irrelevent, because even if you correct it it's going to be wrong in a year.

Comment: I am surprised actually that height is added to the passport. My newborn's passport didn't have any height information. My own passport doesn't mention it either. Interesting information. The photo is of less concern to be honest. Many children naturally smile when looking at the camera, whereas smiling photos are not allowed for passports; making life difficult. I think people understand these things.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Original Posters own Anwer

> == Update
>
> Portuguese consulate never answered my e-mail. I went to Netherlands
>   without issues with her and no one asked about anything related to
>   these problems. I think this info is not important for small children,
>   probably.
>
> Thank you for your comments.